# Xcode 6.3.2 build for OS X 10.7

Tags: xcode, macos

Hope you can help me with a strange problem, no clue what I am doing wrong.

On Xcode 6.3.2 I want to build an app able to run on OS X 10.7. 
So I started with a new Cocoa Application (Obj-C), naming it "Test". I set the Deployment Target to 10.7. Leaving the application empty I can build and run it on my main machine (OS X  10.10.3). Running wt will show an empty window ok.

Now I archive it and in the Organizer export it as a Mac application. Again all works fine, no errors. Now if I run it on the target machine (running 10.7.5) it will start, but no window will show up. Also the menu of the app will only show its name, all other menu items are missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably created the project to use a storyboard, which is not supported by OS X 10.7. You need to use a MainMenu NIB. You also need to make sure you don't use any features that were introduced after 10.7.

Also, when an app fails like this, you should check the console log to see if it logged any errors. You can view that using /Applications/Utilities/Console.app.