# Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication when attempting to debug Mac OS X app on 10.7

Tags: xcode, macos, gdb, nsapplication

I'm attempting to target 10.7 with my Mac OS X app, but when I try running it on a 10.7 machine no window opens and I get "Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication" logged to the console.

When I try to build the app locally to debug, I get "-fobc-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime".  It looks like I need Xcode 5+ which isn't supported on 10.7 so I'm at a loss for how to continue debugging this issue.

Comment: Is it even possible to have a storyboard based OS X app run on 10.7?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from another question.  10.7 doesn't support storyboards.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30954258/873546